# Login vie email as a hosted service (with OAuth)

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth, authorization, email

I'm creating a site with login feature (some functionality reserved for more or less "known" users). Most people will log in using Facebook or Google+ but some will prefer old-fashioned email way, which is way more complicated to develop - you have to take care of your domain reputation, SMTP service, implement password reminder/reset feature, secure it against spammer abuse and so on.

Is there any external email login/auth service (with reasonable prices and privacy policy) where I could redirect user and then get their credentials via OAuth?